# No such file or directory: 'tree2.txt'

Tags: python

So I have this file in my directory but it won't recognize it.

[image: Directory]

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You're running `tree.py` from within the `christmastree` directory, right?  Get the current working directory, then traverse as needed with `os.path.join()` so it's futureproof, and will run on any device.

```
import os

cwd = os .getcwd()  ##  current working directory
filename = 'tree2.txt'
fullpath = os .path .join( cwd, filename )
tree = list( open( fullpath ) .read() .rstrip() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tree = list(open('../christmastree/tree2.txt').read().rstrip())
```